# How can I maximize my car warranty benefits before it expires

Tags: maintenance, audi, warranty, s4

I currently own a 2015 Audi S4 I bought new. Its warranty is about to expire. Although the car seemed pretty trouble free at close to 60K km (knock on wood), I still want to know if there is a common way of making sure you get maximum out of your insurance before it expires?

For example, something like: asking my dealer to inspect certain vital parts of my vehicle or even perform some services that are covered. Btw, this is my first vehicle so I am very concerned about my lack of experience and I plan on keeping my car for another 5 years.

Comment: So what do you want to claim for? They will replace items that are broken but not normal wear and tear. This is not the same as home insurance where people claim items to the value of their premium each year...

Comment: I am not trying to claim anything. I am looking for tips on things you can ask the dealer for simply because the warranty accounts for it.

Comment: Just be honest with the dealership Service Writer, ask him if he can have a technician do a thorough inspection to look for warranty issues, and then fix them before the warranty expires.

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot point to something directly and state, "*This is broke, fix it.*", there's not much you are going to be able to do to utilize your warranty. You need to realize the warranty is put in place by the manufacturer to provide "peace of mind" to the consumer. It is there as a catch all in case something does go wrong with the vehicle. This gives the consumer some bit of protection for as long as the warranty is in effect. Really, the manufacturer is using it mainly to sell their vehicles. When they offer such a warranty, they have a believe their product longevity will exceed the amount of time the warranty is in effect. Without it, they wouldn't sell as many vehicles, so it's a bit of a trade-off for them.

Again, if there's nothing wrong you can point at, there's not much you're going to get out of it. Consider yourself lucky in that it sounds as though you've not had too many issues with your vehicle. Keep up on your maintenance and you should expect it to last the 5+ years you're hoping to get out of it. Nothing mechanical will last forever, but you can definitely prolong their life by keeping up with the maintenance.